# Wordpress redictering loop on specific page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, redirect-loop

I've made a Wordpress webpage which works well, except one specific addres.

When I'm entering all pages, posts etc everything seems fine, but when I try to access specific address (like http://page.com/foo, and only this one) it drops me to redirection loop, and stops on address such like http://page.com/foo////////////////////.

I've checked some things:

1. htaccess-es which may have some influence are OK (only specific 301's exists and standard Wordpress redirection pattern)
2. I'm using redirection plugin ("301 Redirects") but bug exist even if I'm turning plug off
3. On hosting site (ovh) there is not such thing that can make a problem

Where I should try to find the reason? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Check if any other plugin is installed for redirection.

Comment: @dipmala nope, only this one

Comment: Paste htaccess file

Comment: Problem solved boss :)